# Filtering rows based on list conditions in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where one column contains lists of values. I want to filter out/drop the rows where the list in the column contains only values from a predefined valid_values list. Specifically, I want to keep the rows where the list either contains values other than those in valid_values or contains NaN.

Here's my current code:

```
valid_values = ["10a", "10b", "10c", "11a", "11b", "11c"]
df_filtered = df[~df['Foo'].apply(lambda x: pd.isna(x) or any(v not in valid_values for v in x) if isinstance(x, list) else False)]
```

Which lead to:

> TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable

so I also created a function as alternative:

```
def check_valid_values(x):
    valid_values = ["10a", "10b", "10c", "11a", "11b", "11c"]
    if pd.isna(x) or (isinstance(x, list) and all(v in valid_values for v in x)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

df_filtered = df[df['Foo'].apply(check_valid_values)]
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I'm not sure how to resolve these issues without using iterrow+s() and achieve my desired filtering. Could someone please help me understand what's causing these errors and suggest a correct approach to filter the rows as intended?

Thank you in advance for any guidance or suggestions!

Comment: I'm confused. you say at the beginning of your question you want to keep only rows where the `Foo` row's list doesn't have any item in common with `valid_values`, but in your code you try to do the opposite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not entirely sure what you were trying to do, but I gave it a shot:

```py
def check_valid_values(x):
    valid_values = ["10a", "10b", "10c", "11a", "11b", "11c"]
    if x is None or not isinstance(x, list) and pd.isna(x) or isinstance(x, list) and not any(v in valid_values for v in x):
        # 'not any' filters OUT all lists of 'Foo' that have at least one value in common with valid_values.
        # replace 'not any' with 'all' if you're looking to check if all values are in valid_values
        return True
    else:
        return False

df_filtered = df[df['Foo'].apply(check_valid_values)]
```

As you can see I took the liberty of adding `x is None`, as I thought you also wanted to keep `None` values as well as `NaN` (missing) values. feel free to remove it if this is not the case.

The issue was trying to check for `pd.isna(x)` with a list. `pandas.isna()` doesn't accept lists, so i check if x *wasn't* a list before check for `pd.isna(x)`.

As I didn't know if you wanted to filter *out* or *in* the rows where there are common items between `valid_values` and `x`, I decided on filtering them **out** with `not any`.

- Replace it with `all` to filter **in** all rows where `x` **ONLY** contains values that are in `valid_values`.
- Replace it with `any` to filter **in** all rows where `x` has at least **one** value that is in `valid_values`.
- Replace it with `not all` if you want to filter **out** all rows where `x` **ONLY** contains values that are **not** in valid_values.

If you're not sure, just play with those keywords and see what happens.
Hope this helped !
I'll put my whole script here for context.

```py
import pandas as pd


def check_valid_values(x):
    valid_values = ["10a", "10b", "10c", "11a", "11b", "11c"]
    if x is None or not isinstance(x, list) and pd.isna(x) or isinstance(x, list) and not any(v in valid_values for v in x):
        # 'not any' filters OUT all lists of 'Foo' that have at least one value in common with valid_values.
        # replace 'not any' with 'all' if you're looking to check if all values are in valid_values
        return True
    else:
        return False


valid_values = ["10a", "10b", "10c", "11a", "11b", "11c"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo':[
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","othervalue"],
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","10a"],
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","11b"],
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","othervalue"]
                        ],
               'Bar':[
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","10a"], #just to show that 'Bar' isn't checked for valid values
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","othervalue"],
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","othervalue"],
                        ["othervalue","othervalue","othervalue","11c"]
                    ]
            })
            
                
print("before :\n", df)

df_filtered = df[df['Foo'].apply(check_valid_values)]

print("after :\n", df_filtered)
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I changed it to "not all" and it works perfectly